# Running Kafka Mirror Maker 2 in specific port

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Inorder to replicate data between two DC's, I have setupa Kafka MM2. It is running properly. But each time I am restarting, it is starting in different ports.

In order to monitor this application, it would be better if it always runs in same port so that we can monitor that port for any alerts.

For kafka, we would be specifying the ports manually. But for MirrorMaker, there is no option to set the port manually in the properties. Also I tried various options like setting -Dserver.port. But none of them were worked.

Can anyone provide a solution for this ?!

Answer (score 0):

`listeners` is the Kafka Connect property that determines the bound server port

For example, to make it port 8181, `listeners=HTTP://0.0.0.0:8181`

`rest.port` property is deprecated

Comment: I have tried giving this property. But still it doesn't pick up the one which I gave. I given this property in connect-mirror-maker.properties. Apart from that, I also tried rest.port, rest.advertised.port. But none worked. Whether I am missing anything ?

Comment: Actually, just `listeners` - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest And [source code is here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/mirror/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/MirrorMaker.java#L234) for where the properties are parsed

Comment: From the source code and from the logs, I could able to see only null value for the listeners. I have tried setting the value for listeners property as mentioned. But it is not getting picked up it seems. Also I logged the workerProps. But no properties related to listeners or port is present. Whether anything I am missing ?

Comment: Are you using `connect-mirror-maker` or `connect-distributed`? Both load the DistributedConfig class which includes the listeners config

Comment: I am using connect-mirror-maker.  I could find listeners property populated in WorkerConfig class. But they are putting in map with value as null.  Also, connect-mirror-maker.properties will be used as MirrorMakerConfig. But DistributedConfig is getting populated with workerProps where I see no properties related to listeners. Whether any prefix need to be added if it is given in connect-mirror-maker.proeprties ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many different ways and finally decided to go with the following approach:

1. While starting the mirrormaker, I will manually open socketconnection to some fixed port
2. This fixed port will be monitored for the alerts. If this port goes down, it means mirrormaker process has been down.

I have tested this and it is working without any issues.